# Is this question appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-rec

Next semester I'll be teaching a course where we constitute our senior majors as a software development house, working in groups of three or so on projects that faculty in other departments have proposed. The students are competent programmers, but generally have little serious software development experience.

As the Department theorist, it's been a *long* time since I've worked in a professional environment, so my knowledge is decades out of date.

Would a request for methodology suggestions or development tools be appropriate here or would such questions be more appropriate on another site?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67291/computer-science-software-engineering-educators

Comment: @gnat. Thanks, I hadn't considered that site. I'll wait a bit and see what responses I get here (since there are certainly more participants here).

Comment: [Chat] is also a good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would not be appropriate on Programmers.  Our Help Center states that questions asking for recommendations on software tools is off topic.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

You might be interested in the following site, still in public beta.

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the "no tools questions" prohibition, but it seems that "development methodologies" and "software engineering and management" are on-topic, so I could ask for recommendations along those lines, right?

Comment: @RickDecker - Still sounds like that's a polling type request or too broad.  Quite likely that it would be closed.

Comment: @RickDecker If your question is reasonably scoped, demonstrates a real problem you are facing, and isn't explicitly for the purpose of compiling a list of outside references and links then it is appropriate under those categories.  If somebody wishes to recommend software or provide links in an answer that addresses your problem then that is fine, but we generally take a hard line stance on requests for recommendations.